# Is it possible to track a rotating object using Sikuli?

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-x, object-tracking

I want to make a sikuli script that can track a object that rotates and hides behind another object, just like a "find the ball" game. Is it possible? If it is, how can i achieve it?
Maybe even a way to execute another script via sikuli would do the job, solving it externally.

I tried tracking the object with the mouse using a "while exists" script, but since the object is always in different angles, it just crashes

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SikuliX does not have any features that allow to follow the movement of objects in an image, that are constantly changing their pixel content.
This seems to be true in your case.

The only feature that might help here, is onChange(), which can be used to check that a Region changes its pixel content.

But I guess, that a workflow using this feature is rather complex.

Without having your situation on the screen, it is impossible to talk on possible steps to a solution.

So a link to a web-page, that shows the moving ball or a screen-capture-video might help.

RaiMan from SikuliX (sikulix---at---outlook---dot---com)